# How to search for an exact phrase with ytsearch in youtube-dl

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, youtube, youtube-dl

A few search results for this similar question came up, but they were either unanswered, or deleted and wouldn't even show up on Internet Archive, so I hope someone here can help!

Sometimes when you search things in YouTube, it will show a button saying "Showing results for:" and then a slightly different phrase than what I actually wanted to search. Next to that, they have a button saying "Search instead for:" and the actual phrase I wanted to search.

When using ytsearch in youtube-dl, how can I be sure that it's searching for the exact phrase I want, and not some slightly modified phrase YouTube suggests?

Here's an example:

If my search term was "gardneing", YouTube instead shows results for the phrase "gardening", which is not what I was searching for.

Using youtube-dl to do this would look like:

```
youtube-dl "ytsearch1:gardneing"
```

But it would download the first video under "gardening", because that's what it's showing results for.

On the YouTube website, this is just resolved by using double quotes " on either side of the phrase, which will now show me all results under "gardneing", but you can't really do that with youtube-dl, because the double quotes need to be around `ytsearch1:etc`.

So my question is, how can I search for an *exact* phrase in youtube-dl, so that it shows results in the same way it would as putting quotes around the phrase on the website? Is there another option I can pass?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to double quote ytsearch

```
youtube-dl ytsearch1:"gardneing"
```

This shall work.
Or if you really have to, You can use single quotes

```
youtube-dl 'ytsearch1:"gardneing"'
```